# How to build a Slack-like left panel in Django to minimize database access

Tags: django, database, caching

I am working on a Django app that has a left panel similar to Slack's. It shows the channels that the current user has subscribed to. Since this panel is shown for every page, I put it in the base template. My question is that because the panel content is dynamic, it will create a database access (getting the list of channels for the user) each time a page is loaded.

What would be the best way to optimize it? Should I cache the content of the left panel and invalidate it if it changes (if the user subscribed to a new channel or left a channel)? Are there any other options?

Comment: Why optimise it? Does it run slow? If it does not preform, try to find why.

Comment: Just thought that it would generate too many unnecessary DB calls as the content of the left panel does not change frequently.

Comment: Install django debug toolbar and see if that is so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about a single HTML page and don't want to re-engineer the site to use a front-end JavaScript framework with web service calls, caching can save many database calls. While I'd recommend `memcached` or something similar, database caching is the easiest to set up. Add this to settings:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache',
        'LOCATION': 'django_db_cache',
    }
}
```

Then run this command to create the DB cache:

```
django-admin createcachetable
```

Wrap the section of your template is something like this:

```
{% cache 3600 "leftnav-" request.user.get_username %}
.......
{% endcache %}
```

That would create a cache entry for the next hour with the key "leftnav-username" - and you'd have to delete it from the cache when the user adds or deletes and item to it.

You'll probably also want to use a dummy cache in your development environment once you're done. This basically turns off caching in development:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',
    }
}
```

Good luck!